# How to read a csv file using jQuery and html and check a condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, csv

I want to read a csv file using jQuery and html and see if a condition applies to the cell. So basically I have a csv file with transactions and I want to check if that transaction matches with my keyword and then the program would give it a certain id number and I also want to export that to a separate csv.

This is all I got up to:

```
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="csv" aria-describedby="file" aria-label="Upload">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-primary" type="button" id="upload">Upload</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#upload").clicked(function(){

        
      })
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are referring to  a CSV data source that is available to you online (please be aware of possible CORS restrictions) and you want to use it as a basis for further data checks then you can load it asynchronously with jQuery in the following way:

```js
var holidays; // global array of objects (available only after asynchronous loading has finished!)
$.get("https://date.nager.at/PublicHoliday/Country/DE/2023/CSV").done(function(csv){
 holidays=$.csv.toObjects(csv);
 console.log(holidays);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/1.0.21/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery CVS is your friend here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Parsing-Displaying-CSV-Files-jQuery.html.